# Next.js + Taboola Pixel

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use Taboola Pixel with Next.js app and stuck on some difficulties.
After page loaded when I try to track event by clicking on button Pixel tracks a time after page loaded and sum this time to `time to request`. As result I have got more then 3sec `time to request` and Taboola Helper extension show warning: "The pixel took 3.336sec to load. Therefore, some actions may not be tracked." https://help.taboola.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003505113#too-long-load

next 9.5.5,
react 16.13.1

[image]

Maybe someone has already done this problem?